# Can I specify the save location for Delphi .dsk file?

Tags: git, delphi, ide

I want the Delphi IDE to remember which files I had open, etc., but if I enable the "Project Desktop" autosave option (Tools -> Options -> EnvironmentOptions in XE7) it puts the `.dsk` file in the root folder of my source code.

We are using git for our version control, and whenever I do a `git clean -xdf` it deletes the `.dsk` file.

I realize I could use the `-e` option to explicitly exclude this file from a git clean, but really what I want is a way to tell the IDE to save the file somewhere else. Is this possible? If not, any other workaround?

Comment: You could add it to the git ingnore list or the assum unchanged list

Comment: @SariRahal it is already in the `.gitignore`, but due to other interactions we often need the `-x` option, which will remove ignored files.

Comment: You could make a batch file or special build target that runs the right cleanup command and the corresponding follow-up command together. That way, you get consistent results without having to remember too much. You could also define a git alias that automatically excludes DSK files: `git config --global --add alias.dsk-clean "clean -xfd -e *.dsk"`. Then use `git dsk-clean` instead of plain old `git clean`.

Comment: @RobKennedy yeah, an alias might be the best I can do. It'd be nice if I could specify some default args to `clean` in my `.gitconfig` but that doesn't seem to be supported. Oh well. If you want to turn this into an answer I'll accept it since it covers the "If not, any other workaround" piece. I was hoping for something that wouldn't require remembering to do something different, but hey, if the file gets blasted occasionally it's not the end of the world, either.

Comment: Could the downvoter please provide an explanation or suggestion for improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE places the file in the root directory of the project. You cannot influence it to do otherwise.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Delphi sure is awfully free about adding its own files/changes without asking permission (another case in point, just got done selectively committing my changes to a `.dfm` file and reverting all the changes where Delphi was trying to be "helpful").

Comment: Yes, it's commonplace to have to do that